# Row values as column headings

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How can I make the following sql result:

[image]

Be rendered in a result set like this

```
| ID  | Chain Size      | Length  | Hook Type  | Shortening Grab |
|-----|-----------------|---------|------------|-----------------|
| 163 | 7mm (1.5 tonne) | 1 metre | C Hook     |  Yes            |
| 226 | 7mm (1.5 tonne) | 1 metre | C Hook     |  No             |
| 247 | 7mm (1.5 tonne) | 1 metre | Latch Hook |  No             |
```

I know that the values in columns 2,4,6 and 8 (which I want to be headers) will be the same across all rows (but different depending on the initial query).

I believe the approach for what I want is through the use of PIVOT but really struggling to get the desired result.

Thanks

Comment: You could try a simple rename of the column you select. i.e: SELECT id AS ID, attributevalue AS Chain Size FROM table

Comment: I'd really advice to rethink your design.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot"

Comment: Just curious, is your source data in an EAV structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Two or more columns can't have the same name within table. Column's name should be unique. Source table should have following columns: attributeName1, attributeValue1, attributeName2, attributeValue2, ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source data actually looks like this:

[image]

**Static Pivot**

```
Select *
From  YourTable
Pivot (max(attributeValue) For [attributeName] in ([Chain Size],[Length],[Hook Type],[Shortening Grab]) ) p
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Dynamic Approach**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([attributeName]) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select *
From YourTable
Pivot (max(attributeValue) For [attributeName] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

Notice, without an item for column sequence, you'll see that they are alphabetical.